# Does the following identity hold: $ [{A \times B^* + A^* \times B} ]$ = $2Re{[A \times B^*]}$

Tags: complex-analysis, cross-product

This seems to be true at first glance following that $a + a^*$ = $2Re(a)$

In any case, can someone help me verify whether this identity holds?

Note: $\times$ is the cross product

Comment: This identity has nothing difficult in it. Did you try to prove it yourself?

Comment: Yeah you are right. I panicked when I saw the cross product but it is nothing difficult :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LHS is

$$A \times B^* + A^* \times B=\frac12(A^*B^*+AB) +\frac12(AB+A^*B^*)=AB+A^*B^*.$$

The RHS is

$$2\mathrm{Re} (A \times B^*)=\mathrm{Re}(A^*B^*+AB)=\frac{A^*B^*+AB+(A^*B^*+AB)^*}{2}\\=\frac{A^*B^*+AB+AB+A^*B^*}{2}=AB+A^*B^*.$$

So, the equality is an identity.

Comment: Thanks, but how did you reduce that cross product into 1/2 times that sum term in the second equality in the first equation?

Comment: Note that stuff into parentheses is the same. So, $1/2+1/2=1.$

Comment: sorry I meant how did you see that $A \times B^* = 1/2 (A^*B^* + AB)$

Comment: Is this link http://www.solitaryroad.com/c606.html helpful?

Comment: helpful indeed...